# Solidity - Atomic issue impossible to exchange USDT to another token

Tags: ethereum, solidity, cryptocurrency

I have this code :

```
 function buy_with_stablecoins(uint _tid, uint _amount) public { // _tid = 1 = usdt, _tid = 2 = usdc

        require(_tid == 1 || _tid ==2, "Invalid token id");
        require(presale_time>=block.timestamp, "Presale ended");


        // Calculate the amount of token to be sold.

        if(_tid ==1 ){

            require(usdt.allowance(msg.sender, address(this))>= _amount, "Does to have enough allownace to buy");
       
            uint _token_amount = (rate * _amount)/(10*6);

            total_sold += _token_amount;

            usdt.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);

            token.transfer(msg.sender, _token_amount);

        }else{

            require(usdc.allowance(msg.sender, address(this))>= _amount, "Does to have enough allownace to buy");
            uint _token_amount = (rate * _amount)/(10*6);

            total_sold += _token_amount;

            usdc.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);

            token.transfer(msg.sender, _token_amount);
        }

        _addParticipant(msg.sender);  // Register participant
    }
```

I don't know why it's not working it seems I have an error when I try to send USDT token to the presale contract the presale contract should send me my token contribution in exchange but not working...

I tried to deploy this contract with the function buy with stablecoin but I don't understand what is the issue ?

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Your code logic seems fine. Maybe you can Elaborate on your question.
If you thought it was code error, consider these points:token addresses, token allowance, rate calculation, token transfer function, gas limit, debugging, testing environment, transaction logs, contract deployment, external dependencies etc.